# Complicated query to get opening balance, added_qty, reduced_qty and ending balance for a specific period

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to figure out a way to get opening balance, added_qty, reduced_qty and ending balance
for a specific period with 1 mysql query.
I have the following tables:
[image]

Explanations for Table Loadings
FIELD loading_type has the following meanings:
1 - initial loading / first time product qty added
2 - additional loading / added additional qty
3 - reduced qty / could be various reasons, for example reduced by order, than order_id > 0 | reduced becaused missing | reduced because broken

The next important thing here is that reduced by order qty must be taken only if paid_date from TABLE orders has date between given period
PLEASE NOTE that row #3 from Table Loadings was not taken in the expected results as reduce_qty because its order paid_date is in January next year so that's why its being counted in reduce_qty for January

and

[image]

The expected results should look like:

[image]

or if you change the period to
[image]

or  if you change the period to
[image]

I have prepared a dump for sample databases as following:

```
--
-- Table structure for table `Loadings`
--
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Loadings`;
    CREATE TABLE `Loadings` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `added_qty` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
      `reduce_qty` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
      `loading_type` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
      `order_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
      `added_date` datetime NOT NULL
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


    INSERT INTO `Loadings` VALUES(1, 4, 3, 0, 1, 0, '2020-12-03 08:46:40');
    INSERT INTO `Loadings` VALUES(2, 4, 1, 0, 2, 0, '2020-12-15 08:46:40');
    INSERT INTO `Loadings` VALUES(3, 4, 0, 1, 3, 1, '2020-12-16 08:46:40');
    INSERT INTO `Loadings` VALUES(4, 4, 0, 2, 3, 2, '2020-12-21 08:46:40');
    INSERT INTO `Loadings` VALUES(5, 4, 2, 0, 2, 0, '2021-01-05 08:46:40');
    INSERT INTO `Loadings` VALUES(6, 4, 0, 1, 3, 3, '2021-01-06 08:46:40');


    ALTER TABLE `Loadings`  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

    ALTER TABLE `Loadings`  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=7;
    COMMIT;

--
-- Table structure for table `demo_orders`
--

    CREATE TABLE `demo_orders` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `order_status` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
      `paid_date` datetime NOT NULL
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


    INSERT INTO `demo_orders` VALUES(1, 4, 'finished', '2021-01-05 08:46:40');
    INSERT INTO `demo_orders` VALUES(2, 4, 'finished', '2020-12-22 08:46:40');
    INSERT INTO `demo_orders` VALUES(3, 4, 'finished', '2021-01-05 08:46:40');

    ALTER TABLE `demo_orders`  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

    ALTER TABLE `demo_orders`  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=4;
    COMMIT;
```

So far I started with this query:

```
select concat("Opening balance: ", 
sum(added_qty-reduce_qty)) as opening from Loadings where product_id = "4" and 
month(added_date) = month( date_sub("2021-02-01", interval day("2021-02-01")+1 day) ) and 
year(added_date) = year( date_sub("2021-02-01", interval day("2021-02-01")+1 day) ) 

union all select concat("Debit: ", sum(reduce_qty)) as debit from Loadings where product_id = "4" and 
month(added_date) = month( date_sub("2021-02-01", interval day("2021-02-01")+1 day) ) and 
year(added_date) = year( date_sub("2021-02-01", interval day("2021-02-01")+1 day) ) 

union all select concat("Credit: ", sum(added_qty)) as credit from Loadings where product_id = "4" and 
month(added_date) = month( date_sub("2021-02-01", interval day("2021-02-01")+1 day) ) and 
year(added_date) = year( date_sub("2021-02-01", interval day("2021-02-01")+1 day) );
```

but the customer added a requirement that orders that not paid between the period date must not counted and this totally confused me how the query should looks like..
AT this point the above query seems very poor approach but I added because #Shadow suggested to demponstrate some query attempt..
Any help highly appreciated !

Comment: Great that you've provided DDLs, but please don't post pictures of text.

Comment: #Strawberry - maybe you mean not to post pictures of the tables? I did it as I was thinking its not important since there is a database dump ..

Comment: Pls provide a reasonable attempt at solving your problem along with description of where you got stuck or what error message you received. At the moment  your post is just a dump of requirements expecting a full solution from scratch, not a question! Also, in real life ERP systems do store opening and closing balances separately because it is very resource consuming to calculate these from the beginning of time a product first appears in your system. Therefore I do think this is a study question, which makes it even more important to include an attempt to solve it.

Comment: Dear Shadow, I added my first query attempt and also added that explanaition that the customer changed requirements what to be included in the results and therefor I am stacked without knowing how to change the query and connect the second table demo_orders in it.. The products will have a short lifetime, only couple recoreds In/OUT and than they are gone..So shouldn't be that resource consuming..